# Opengl texture lookup mask

Tags: opengl, interpolation

I have a texture which has unwanted black pixels . I want to discard its impact when i do a tex2d or tex3d with linear interpolation ON. The problem is on the edge where black and white meet am getting interpolated values. I don't want to set lookup to POINT.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two conceptual solutions:

1. Restrict the tex-coords to never sample from any location which would incorporate the unwanted "border" pixels. This can be done by clamping the tex coords to the *centers* of the outmost texels of your usable range.

   a) By directly modifying the tex-coords. This will not require any modification of the shaders (and would work with the fixed-function pipeline). However, this means that you lose a pixel-exact mapping and lose one pixel in horizontal and vertical direction.

   b) By clamiping the texcoords directly before sampling the texture in the shader. This requires that the information of the usable range is available to the shader. However, in the case of an axis-aligned rectangle as suggested by your picture, this can be represented by a vec4. As this is a property of the texture, using an uniform for that seems appropriate. Maybe you can even get away with constants in the shader.
2. "Fix" the value after sampling. Now this might sound like a complex and difficult operation, but actually, it is quite easy to accomplish. You need an extra mask which is 1 everywhere where your texture is valid, and 0 where the black border is. If you use only up to 3 channels, you can simply add this as the fourth texture channel. Otherwise, you might need an extra texture (with the same filter settings), though. This also requires that the "unwanted" data in your texture is always black, so contributing 0 to the interpolation. In that case, you need the sample of the 0/1-mask and can use that to re-normalize the sample of the acutal color simply by

   ```
   vec4 color = texture(samplerColor, texCoord);
   float mask = texture(samplerMask, texCoord).r; // or mask = color.a
   vec4 fixed_folor = color / mask;
   ```

   This even works with more complex filters like mipmapping and anisotropic filtering.